# Easier way to get individual records, and write them automatically

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Well there has got to be an easier, more automatic way to this.
I'm basically querying the database for each radio button.
This is all working, but it'll be a pain for me to implement more, can anyone give me some tips?

This is what I've done so far.

**checkStatus.php**

```
    require_once 'connectdb.php';

$skap_NummerID_A1_1 = "A1-1";
$skap_NummerID_A1_2 = "A1-2";
$skap_NummerID_A1_3 = "A1-3";
$skap_NummerID_A1_4 = "A1-4";
$skap_NummerID_A1_5 = "A1-5";

    //THIS IS LOCKER NUMBER A1_1
$displayStatus_query_A1_1 = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer ='$skap_NummerID_A1_1'";
$resultStatus_A1_1 = $connect_DB->query($displayStatus_query_A1_1);
if ($resultStatus_A1_1->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($rowStatus_A1_1 = $resultStatus_A1_1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $skap_sjekkStatus_A1_1 = $rowStatus_A1_1["Status"];
    }}

//THIS IS LOCKER NUMBER A1_2
$displayStatus_query_A1_2 = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer ='$skap_NummerID_A1_2'";
$resultStatus_A1_2 = $connect_DB->query($displayStatus_query_A1_2);
if ($resultStatus_A1_2->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($rowStatus_A1_2 = $resultStatus_A1_2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $skap_sjekkStatus_A1_2 = $rowStatus_A1_2["Status"];
    }}

//THIS IS LOCKER NUMBER A1_3
$displayStatus_query_A1_3 = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer ='$skap_NummerID_A1_3'";
$resultStatus_A1_3 = $connect_DB->query($displayStatus_query_A1_3);
if ($resultStatus_A1_3->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($rowStatus_A1_3 = $resultStatus_A1_3->fetch_assoc()) {
        $skap_sjekkStatus_A1_3 = $rowStatus_A1_3["Status"];
    }}

//THIS IS LOCKER NUMBER A1_4
$displayStatus_query_A1_4 = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer ='$skap_NummerID_A1_4'";
$resultStatus_A1_4 = $connect_DB->query($displayStatus_query_A1_4);
if ($resultStatus_A1_4->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($rowStatus_A1_4 = $resultStatus_A1_4->fetch_assoc()) {
        $skap_sjekkStatus_A1_4 = $rowStatus_A1_4["Status"];
    }}

//THIS IS LOCKER NUMBER A1_5
$displayStatus_query_A1_5 = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer ='$skap_NummerID_A1_5'";
$resultStatus_A1_5 = $connect_DB->query($displayStatus_query_A1_5);
if ($resultStatus_A1_5->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($rowStatus_A1_5 = $resultStatus_A1_5->fetch_assoc()) {
        $skap_sjekkStatus_A1_5 = $rowStatus_A1_5["Status"];
    }}
```

**skap.php**

```
                <input type="radio" id="A1-1" name="radios" value="A1-1" class="radio-toolbar-all-input" <?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_1 === "Aktiv") {echo "disabled";}?>>
                <label class="<?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_1 === "Aktiv") {echo $changecsstoo_Aktiv;} else {echo $changecsstoo_Inaktiv;}?>" for="A1-1">A1-1</label> 

                <input type="radio" id="A1-2" name="radios" value="A1-2" class="radio-toolbar-all-input" <?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_2 === "Aktiv") {echo "disabled";}?>>
                <label class="<?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_2 === "Aktiv") {echo $changecsstoo_Aktiv;} else {echo $changecsstoo_Inaktiv;}?>" for="A1-2">A1-2</label> 

                <input type="radio" id="A1-3" name="radios" value="A1-3" class="radio-toolbar-all-input" <?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_3 === "Aktiv") {echo "disabled";}?>>
                <label class="<?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_3 === "Aktiv") {echo $changecsstoo_Aktiv;} else {echo $changecsstoo_Inaktiv;}?>" for="A1-3">A1-3</label> 

                <input type="radio" id="A1-4" name="radios" value="A1-4" class="radio-toolbar-all-input" <?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_4 === "Aktiv") {echo "disabled";}?>>
                <label class="<?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_4 === "Aktiv") {echo $changecsstoo_Aktiv;} else {echo $changecsstoo_Inaktiv;}?>" for="A1-4">A1-4</label> 

                <input type="radio" id="A1-5" name="radios" value="A1-5" class="radio-toolbar-all-input" <?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_5 === "Aktiv") {echo "disabled";}?>>
                <label class="<?php if ($skap_sjekkStatus_A1_5 === "Aktiv") {echo $changecsstoo_Aktiv;} else {echo $changecsstoo_Inaktiv;}?>" for="A1-5">A1-5</label>
```

And I have like 25 of these, and I'm going to need to make even more, but I was wondering is there an easier way to do this?

And for those of you that are wondering, this is http://prntscr.com/bjziml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whenever you find yourself repeating code like this, its usually a sign you need to use a simple loop:

```
$displayStatusResults = [];

$displayStatusQuery = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer IN('A1-1','A1-2','A1-3','A1-4','A1-5')";

$result = $connect_DB->query($displayStatusQuery);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $displayStatusResults[$row['Skap_Nummer']] = $row['Status'];
    }
}
```

skap.php

```
<div class="row">
<?php $count=0;
 foreach($displayStatusResults as $skap => $status): $count++;?>

    <input 
        type="radio" 
        id="<?=$skap?>" 
        name="radios" 
        value="<?=$skap?>" 
        class="radio-toolbar-all-input" 
        <?= ($status === "Aktiv")? 'disabled':''?>>

    <label 
        class="<?= ($status === "Aktiv")? $changecsstoo_Aktiv : $changecsstoo_Inaktiv?>" 
        for="<?=$skap?>">
        <?=$skap?>
    </label> 

    <?php if($count==8):?>
</div><!--end row--><div class="row">    
    <?php endif; $count=0;?>

<?php endforeach;?>
</div><!--end row-->
```

Comment: EXTREMELY close to what I wanted, but what about when I want them shown as in the picture? THANK you btw

Comment: @Nniouz im not sure what you mean, im probably missing something but as far as i can tell, the html should be the same with my code, so it should display the same?

Comment: Hey Steve, if I wanted the rows to start at A1-1 and stop at A1-8, then continiue underneath it. so that A2-1 starts and ends at A2-8?

Comment: @Nniouz add a counter in the loop, when it reaches the required count, close the current row, start a new one, and reset the counter.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for asking you so much. It gave me an error with the ":" at "$count++:", so I removed the ":" and now it shows, but it doesnt stop at 8. http://prntscr.com/bkf4eb

Comment: Oops, `$count++:` should be `$count++;//<--note semicolon, not full colon`

Comment: Thank you for that, but it still doesnt stop at 8 :/ if you click the picture I uploaded, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I guess thats just a mechanic of where the incrementing and checking falls in the loop - adjust the number `$if($count==?)` accordingly and see how you get on

Comment: It doesnt change at all :o
This is what my checkStatus.php looks like,
$displayStatusQuery = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer IN('A1-1','A1-2','A1-3','A1-4','A1-5','A1-6','A1-7','A1-8','A2-1','A2-2','A2-3','A2-4','A2-5','A2-6','A2-7','A2-8')";

Comment: Do you have an actual live link? Without seeing the generated html and css, i have no idea what effects the display - i just picked a dummy css class `row` as an example - i dont know how your actual code denotes a new row unfortunatly

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. But I'm not able to create a live link, however, I copied the CSS into a pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/8TnkRxi0

Answer (score 1):

checkstatus.php

```
$nummers = array("A1-1", "A1-2", "A1-3", "A1-4", "A1-5");
$output = array();

foreach($nummers as $nummer) {
    $output[$nummer] = array();
    //THIS IS LOCKER NUMBER A1_1
$query = "SELECT Skap_Nummer, Status FROM testskap WHERE Skap_Nummer ='$nummer'";
$result = $connect_DB->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $output[$nummer][] = $row["Status"];
    }}
}
```

skap.php

```
$nummers = array("A1-1", "A1-2", "A1-3", "A1-4", "A1-5");
foreach($nummer as $nummer) {
    echo '<input type="radio" id="'.$nummer.'" name="radios" value="'.$nummer.'" class="radio-toolbar-all-input" '.($output[$nummer] === "Aktiv") ? "disabled" : "").'>
        <label class="'.($output[$nummer] === "Aktiv") ? $changecsstoo_Aktiv : $changecsstoo_Inaktiv).'" for="'.$nummer.'">'.$nummer.'</label>';
}
```

you should get $nummers array from some config file